# 400 bad request from twilio's REST API using twilio-ruby

Tags: ruby, api, rest, twilio

I'm trying to get started with Twilio's REST API using the rubygem [twilio-ruby](https://www.twilio.com/docs/ruby/install), and I've hit a snag. Here's my code:

```
h = {:From => "123-123-1234", :To => "123-123-1234", :Body => "hey"}
account = Twilio::RestAccount.new(ACCOUNT_SID, ACCOUNT_TOKEN)
resp = account.request("/#{API_VERSION}/Accounts/#{ACCOUNT_SID}/SMS/Messages", 'POST', h)
```

Which gives the following output:

```
warning: peer certificate won't be verified in this SSL session
=> #<Net::HTTPBadRequest 400 Bad Request readbody=true>
```

I've also tried:

```
 h = {:From => "123-123-1234", :To => "123-123-1234", :Body => "hey"}
Net::HTTP.post_form URI.parse("http://api.twilio.com/2008-08-01/#{ACCOUNT_SID}/SMS/Messages"), h
```

Which give the following output:

```
Net::HTTPBadResponse (wrong status line: "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN\">"):
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Should have inspected the body of the resp:

```
<Message>The 'to' phone number provided is not yet verified for this account.  While your account is in Trial Mode, you may only send SMS messages to verified numbers.  Upgrade to a Full Twilio account to send to any phone number.</Message>
```

Comment: Yeah during the trial you have to verify numbers first. Once you upgrade and buy a real number you can send to any valid number. If you have any more issues, feel free to email me jsheehan@twilio.com

Comment: I have to buy a number from you guys in order to verify it, correct?